# Weird lingering data in MatLab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have the following code (it is reproducible):

```
clear figure
nSites = 3;

ha = tight_subplot(nSites,1,[.01 .01],[.1 .1],[.1 .1]);
display(ha);
for ii = 1:nSites; 
    axes(ha(ii));
    yData=randn(365,1); 
    plot(yData);
    if ii~=nSites
        set(ha,'XTickLabel','');
    else
        set(ha,'XTickLabel','');
        NumTicks=6;
        L = get(gca,'XLim');
        set(gca,'XTick',linspace(L(1),L(2),NumTicks));
        datetick('x','mm/dd','keepticks');  
    end 
end
```

As you can see from the line that says `yData=randn(365,1);`, there are 365 data points (one year).

However, when you run this, you'll notice that it plots from 1/1 to 2/3, which is more than one year (400 values).

Why is this??  Is there a default value I'm not aware of?  There are no NaN values, so this is a mystery to me....

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Can't replicate the problem without `tight_subplot()`. What does this do? Sounds like it should be setting the axis `xlim` based on the description of your problem.

Comment: It's from here:   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight-subplot      Also, this is datetick:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html                  Thanks for asking!

Comment: Also note that `clear figure` actually clears a variable named `figure`. If you want to actually clear the current figure of its contents use the function `clf()`.

Comment: I am afraid that I am unable to reproduce the problem. It may be the problem described by [Michael J](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749544/weird-lingering-data-in-matlab-plot#comment49555129_30749544). Otherwise, the number of data points I got after 1 run is exactly 365 (`q = get(ha(1)); get(q.Children)`).

Comment: Matlab adjusts the axis limits using some heuristic. My guess is also that you just have to explicitly set the limits using `xlim`.